# How to add Yii2 jui datepicker to filter field in GridView

Tags: gridview, datepicker, yii2

I'm using the same code as I used to add in ActiveForm, but it doesn't work:

What i sthe correct way to add jui datepicker in filter field for gridview?

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'list_id',
            [
                'attribute' => 'channel',
                'value' => 'channel.title',
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'list_date',
                'value' => 'list_date',
                'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::className(), ['language' => 'ru', 'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yyyy']),
            ],
            'make_date',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widget params are wrong and you should use `html` or `raw` format :

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'list_date',
            'value' => 'list_date',
            'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget(['language' => 'ru', 'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yyyy']),
            'format' => 'html',
        ],
```

Read more about [Data Formatting](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatting.html#other).

Answer (score 16):

I tried this and works fine:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'updated_at',
    'value' => 'updated_at',
    'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget([
        'model'=>$searchModel,
        'attribute'=>'updated_at',
        'language' => 'ru',
        'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
    ]),
    'format' => 'html',
],
```

Then, you must add this line to your Search Model:

```
$query->andFilterWhere([

    ...

    'DATE(updated_at)' => $this->updated_at,
]);
```

Make sure the date formats are identical.

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code for filer by date picker.

**First import datepicker**

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
```

Then use below code in gridview

```
[
             'attribute' => 'order_date',
             'value' => 'order_date',
             'format' => 'raw',
             'label' => "Order Date",
             'filter' => DatePicker::widget([
                 'model' => $searchModel,
                 'name' => 'OrdersdropSearch[order_date]',
                 'value' => ArrayHelper::getValue($_GET, "OrdersdropSearch.order_date"),
                 'pluginOptions' => [
                     'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                     'autoclose' => true,
                 ]
             ])
         ],
```

Search model will be same.

Answer (score 3):

```
 [
            'attribute' => 'updated_at',
            'value' => 'updated_at',
            },
            'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget([
                    'model'=>$searchModel,
                    'attribute'=>'updated_at',
                    'language' => 'ru',
                    'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                ]),
            'format' => 'html',
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'updated_at',
            'value' => 'updated_at',
            //'format' => ['date', 'php:d.m.Y'],
            'options' => ['width' => '115'],
            'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget(
                [
                    'name' => 'NewsSearch[updated_at]',
                    'value' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getValue($_GET, 'NewsSearch.updated_at'),
                    'language' => 'ru',
                    'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                    // 'model' => $searchModel,
                    // 'attribute' => 'updated_at',
                    'options' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                    ],
                ]
            ),
        ],
```

1. Avoid to use 'attribute'=> 'updated_at' in 'filter' section;
2. Specify direct 'name' attribute (that name will be given for corresponding input in filter row)